# Complete Story unlocks this skill...but I own Complete Story

Tags: trine-2

I own Trine 2: Complete Story, which I bought "as is" (no DLCs applied). Now, higher level skill still tell me a padlock and say: "Complete Story unlocks this skill". Steam tells me I own Complete Story, yet nowhere in the game it says that it actually is that.

How should I proceed? Re-download the game?

Comment: Could it be that the game is saying you need to complete the game once before the skill is unlocked?

Comment: No, I'm pretty certain that it's refering to its "Complete Edition" version which is called Complete Story...or am I wrong here?

Comment: Not wrong. It's in reference to the Complete Story DLC. I just didn't see the need to correct @PrivatePansy since I was writing up the answer. I looked into this mess back when I got a second copy from a Humble Bundle and was wondering if it was worth redeeming for DLC or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You confusingly may not actually own Trine 2: Complete Story, but just Trine 2. Trine 2 was renamed to Complete Story, but people didn't automagically get upgraded to Complete Story and only had the item renamed. Check your Trine 2 DLC and verify whether you have either Complete Story or Gobiln Menace DLC. **If you don't have the correct DLC associated with your game, then you don't have Complete Story and need to buy the "Complete Story Upgrade" to access the locked content.**

From the [developer](http://steamcommunity.com/app/35720/discussions/0/648812917041829842/):

> Trine 2 and Goblin Menace were merged under the same title with our recent big patch, and so they became Complete Story. That name, by mistake, replaced plain Trine 2 as well. So now everything is called Complete Story and that indeed is a bit confusing!
>
> This is relevant because mistakenly the game doesn't tell you that you in fact need the upgrade to be able to get the new skills and levels that come with the Goblin Menace DLC. So to get the upgrade you'd need to go to the Trine 2: Complete Story page and scroll down to find the Buy Trine 2: Complete Story Upgrade option.

Comment: Hmmm...sounds bad. I do not have any DLCs...I bought the game recently as "Trine 2: Complete Story". In-game there is indeed the possibility to buy "Complety Story", clicking which takes me to a Steam page which says that theres no content I could buy/download. In addition its page for Trine 2:Complete Story tells me that I already own it

Comment: Ok, now I see what you mean...I've been to Trine's Steam page and found the Upgrade at the bottom. So I really got sold Trine 2: Complete Story without Complete Story?

Comment: You have to scroll down on the Steam page. There's an entry that says "Buy Trine 2: Complete Story Upgrade" and that is going to give you all the DLC. Steam will tell you you already own it if you own either this or the Goblin Menace DLC. If you bought it as "Complete Story," [this should not be necessary](http://steamcommunity.com/app/35720/discussions/0/846955554728511822/#c846959998008359675). I suggest contacting their support as indicated [here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/35720/discussions/0/846965056816040694/). It's support@frozenbyte.com